# Is there a path-autocomplete extension on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I used to code on Visual Studio Code. Now, i'm trying to learn how to code on Visual Studio 2017 as it will be more beneficial for me. So far, it's so good.

But there is one thing which i miss on VS which is, in VSC, there was a neat extension, called Path Intellisense which autocompleted (or showed suggestions for) `./../file` style file-paths. While coding in javascript (ExpressJS to be exact) i got no suggestions for file path autocomplete. Also, i didnt get any extensions to do so.

Those dot style file paths confuse me and i would really like an extension, or a workaround, in VS to help me with that. Are there any extensions for this?

E.g.[image]

Comment: "While coding in javascript (ExpressJS to be exact) i got no suggestions for file path autocomplete. " Do you mean the path intellisense not works in VS 2017 html file or JS file? I checked the HTML file like your shared video, it seems works fine like VS code, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCVu4DS6eIBA-GT-, if i misunderstand your issue, could you please share another video about your VS 2017? I will test it again

Comment: @Sara-MSFT The gif i shared is an example. It (path intellisense) works in HTML files. It isn't working in JS files. That's where i wanted it to work.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT ok. Some magic happened and Intellisense started showing suggestions for file path. Not sure how it started happening. Thanks anyways.

Comment: So glad to hear that your issue is gone, thanks for your update.